# How can I get the current date and time from the GPS sensor in FireMonkey for Android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

How can I get the current date time from GPS/glonas/baido satellites on my mobile device with Delphi Android programming?

At this time I can just get longitude and latitude from the location sensor.

```
procedure TForm1.LocationSensor1LocationChanged(Sender: TObject;
  const OldLocation, NewLocation: TLocationCoord2D);
var
  LDecSeparator: String;
begin
  LDecSeparator := FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator;
  FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator := '.';
  // Show current location
  ListBoxItemLatitude.ItemData.Detail  := Format('%2.6f', [NewLocation.Latitude]);
  ListBoxItemLongitude.ItemData.Detail := Format('%2.6f', [NewLocation.Longitude]);
end;
```

I know it's easier to use GSM network for time but there is no mobile network available on my case.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you connect location sensor from the provided framware it just provide you location data

but you can get raw data and grab time data

FYI

**because the handset companies using chap gps hardware's on their product,the output data have low accuracy**

for example data is sampling in 1Hz rate so the best value you get is accuracy 1 second:

use this code:

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      LocationManagerService: JObject;
      location : JLocation;
    begin
      if not Assigned(FLocationManager) then
      begin
        LocationManagerService := SharedActivityContext.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap((LocationManagerService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
        if not Assigned(locationListener) then
          locationListener := TLocationListener.Create(self);
        FLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 10, locationListener,
            TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper);
      end;                      

      location := FLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(location.getTime.ToString);
    end;
```

this output is like `1505216957000` time stamp , but for low accuracy the last 3 digit is always 0 so you must remove `000` from last of number and then convert it to your time zone

Comment: Why not just get the timestamp from the last sample in the `OnLocationChanged` event that OP uses?

Comment: your provided code not working on android emulator,i tested on 10.2 now.also `FLocationManager`provide some more status data and its more reliable,try it your self..

Comment: In what way is "more reliable"? It's the same interface as consumed inside `TUIAndroidLocationSensor` class. What I can see is unfinished (thus untested) code. Shame on EMBT.

Comment: casting like `TCustomLocationSensor(Sender)` cause the app crash.i testes 3-4 times in different ways on tokyo and android 7.1.

Comment: Aha. I see. So it should be `LastPosTime := TLocationSensor(Sender).Sensor.TimeStamp;`. I'll try to install that Android thing :)

Comment: @Victoria "Unfinished" is a recurring theme: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16610

Answer (score 1):

This is not the GPS network time. It is the last valid Location *FIX* by the GPS receiver, which could be some time ago.